# What are the light brown spots on coriander leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, herbs, container-gardening

In the last 2 days I noticed there are light brown spots all over my coriander leaves. It's in a pot placed by the window. I live in Singapore so it's sunny throughout the year.

The patches and spots look like the plant has got measles.

Can someone advise me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell, without a picture, but indoors, I'd suspect fungal rather than bacterial infection (because of the drier foliage conditions). Look for pests under the leaves, which would be sucking juices. If there are none, it's likely a fungus. Try removing affected growth and treating regrowth appropriately, if symptoms reappear.

On another note, this herb loves the outdoors, so if it's not too hot (below 85) and it's not freezing at night, I'd try to find a way to get that thing outside.